# Error while getting documents from mongoDb using c#

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, asp.net-core-2.2, mongodb.driver

I'm trying to get document from mongoDB using .net core2.2 console application. i uploaded mongoDB.driver nuget package when ever i'm tring to run code locally it is giving mongo document as expected but after deployment i'm getting below error.

**Could not load file or assembly 'MongoDB.Libmongocrypt, Version=1.0.0.0**

below is the code which

```
MongoDbConnection connection = new MongoDbConnection("DBConnection");
                MongoClient _mongoClient = connection.MongoConnection;

                IMongoDatabase lumenDb = _mongoClient.GetDatabase("Database");Collection              
                var document = collection.Find(doc
                  => doc.ConversationId == model.ConversationId).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Are you running this on MacOS/Linux?

Comment: yup this is linux

Comment: I'm not sure if it's supported yet - https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-2748